# Can I change this Query into a method?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and have to query a "Project" property a lot, which has a lot of properties which have to be included in the query, making the query bloated:

```
var project = await this.ProjectRepository.GetRaw().Where(x => x.ID == id).Include(x => x.Leader).Include(x => x.Users).Include(x => x.Firm).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Please not that GetRaw() returns a IQueryable

Is there a way to construct some helper method where the "include" portion is added, while I dynamically pass in the rest of the query?

something like that:

```
public async Task<List<Project>> GetProjects(query)
{
  return this.ProjectRepository.GetRaw().Include(x => x.Leader).Include(x => x.Users).Include(x => x.Firm) + query;
}
```

usage something like that:

```
public ProjectController
{
  public void Test()
  {
    var result = GetProjects.Where(x => x.ID == 0).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your repository is not generic and is called a `ProjectRepository` (specific to prjects), then it's its own responsibility to return a `Project` that is already including the appropriate data.

Comment: Hmmm why not just passing the `Expression<Func<Project, bool>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should look more like this:

```
public ObjectQuery<Project> GetProjects()
{
  return this.ProjectRepository.GetRaw()
                               .Include(x => x.Leader)
                               .Include(x => x.Users)
                               .Include(x => x.Firm);
}
```

Usage would look like this then:

```
var result = GetProjects().Where(x => x.ID == 0).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the expression as parameter and return it as `IQueryable<T>` so it can be continued by another query.

```
public IQueryable<Project> GetProjects(Expression<Func<Project, bool> query)
{
    return this.ProjectRepository.GetRaw()
        .Include(x => x.Leader)
        .Include(x => x.Users)
        .Include(x => x.Firm)
        .Where(query);
}
```

Usage.

```
var project = await GetProjects(x => x.ID == 0).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: In your usage the **GetProjects()** method doesnt have the argument **query** specified

Comment: That is a good idea, but I like T_Ds answer a little bit more, because the where clause is not a fixed part.

Comment: @ChristianSauer, I thought u need a fixed where clause based on the sample usage, in that case, his answer is more preferable